# Cannot print in ie 11

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing, internet-explorer-11

I found this solution to print:

```
  function Print() {
  if (document.queryCommandSupported('print')) {
document.execCommand('print', false, null);
  }
  else {
    window.parent.<framename>.focus();
    window.print();
  }
}
```

Although I have several iframes rather than only one. What is the best way to write that for several iframes?

Comment: Your Print command is executed from the iframe?

Comment: No. That is the problem. My current print button is for multiple iframes:

Comment: function printall() {
      window.print();
      for (var i=0; i<window.frames.length; i++) {
        alert('Click here AFTER you have sent document ' + (i+1) + ' to the printer.');
        window.frames[i].focus();
        window.frames[i].print();
      }
    }

Comment: I am trying to incorporate the document.execCommand('print', false, null) rather than what I have

Comment: Do you mean you want to use the document.execCommand() method for each iframes, and print each iframe one by one?

Comment: Not one by one. All in one page. Or is that not possible with document.exec? Like loop through all the frames.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the document.execCommand('print', false, null) is similar with window.print() method, you could use either of them to print the whole page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printPage() {
        window.print();
        //document.execCommand('print', false, null);

        ////print each frames
        //for (var k = 0; k < window.frames.length; k++) {
        //    window.frames[k].focus();
        //    window.frames[k].print();
        //}
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This works. Thanks for the answer. Although I still cannot unfortunately print to pdf in ie as I thought by replacing window.print with document.execCommand